# How to make NLog v5 work with Avalonia Android

Tags: c#, android, nlog, avalonia

Recently I update NLog version from 4 to 5 and I have an issue now.

Originally I put my NLog.config in asset folder and NLog would auto scan and load it.

But after I upgrade to 5 and follow the way in the [document](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html), it's not working anymore.

I set my NLog.config to be embedded resource and call `LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAssemblyResource(typeof(MainActivity).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);` in `OnCreate()`

How do I make it work correctly?

Comment: Remember to update `NLog.config` to have build-action `embedded resource`. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Explicit-NLog-configuration-loading#loading-nlog-configuration-from-xamarin-resource

Comment: @RolfKristensen I already do that. But not working.

Comment: At the bottom of same [page](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Explicit-NLog-configuration-loading#xamarin-android) there is also a code-example of how to explictly load a file from Android `Assets`. Alternative you can consider using `NLog.LogManager.Setup(),LoadConfiguration(builder => )` to build [NLog-configuration from code](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-from-code). Maybe possible work-arounds until someone arrives that knows about the Xamarin-platform and can explain why embedded resources are not working for you on Android.

Comment: @RolfKristensen I think it's working. I checked the logger setting with break points and they were looked good. But the log file still doesn't show up. I set the path to `/storage/emulated/0/Download/log_data.log`.

Comment: If you can redirect the [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) to output to some location that works, then you check the output from NLog InternalLogger for clues why FileTarget is not working. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: @RolfKristensen Tank you very much! It's working now. The reason is something wrong in my rules in NLog.config. Your suggestion is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can load NLog configuration from embedded [assembly resource](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Explicit-NLog-configuration-loading#loading-nlog-config-from-assembly-resource):

```
LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAssemblyResource(typeof(MainActivity).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

Also you can redirect Avalonia logging output to NLog by registering `ILogSink` for NLog:

```cs
using Avalonia.Logging;
using NLog;

namespace Logging
{
    public class NLogSink : ILogSink
    {
        private readonly LogEventLevel _level;
        private readonly HashSet<string>? _areas;

        public NLogSink(
            LogEventLevel minimumLevel,
            IList<string>? areas = null)
        {
            _level = minimumLevel;
            _areas = areas?.Count > 0 ? new HashSet<string(areas) : null;
        }

        public bool IsEnabled(LogEventLevel level, string area)
        {
            return level >= _level && (_areas?.Contains(area) ?? true);
        }

        public void Log(LogEventLevel level, string area, object? source, string messageTemplate)
        {
            if (IsEnabled(level, area))
            {
                Nvar logger = Resolve(source?.GetType(), area);
                logger.Log(LogLevelToNLogLevel(level), messageTemplate, propertyValues);
            }
        }

        public void Log(LogEventLevel level, string area, object? source, string messageTemplate, params object?[] propertyValues)
        {
            if (IsEnabled(level, area))
            {
                var logger = Resolve(source?.GetType(), area);
                logger.Log(LogLevelToNLogLevel(level), messageTemplate, propertyValues);
            }
        }

        private ConcurrentDictionary<string, NLog.Logger> _loggerCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, NLog.Logger>();

        public static NLog.ILogger Resolve(Type? source, string? area)
        {
           var loggerName = source?.ToString() ?? area;
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loggerName))
               loggerName = typeof(NLogSink).ToString();

           if (!_loggerCache.TryGetValue(loggerName, out var logger))
           {
              logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(loggerName);
              _loggerCache.TryAdd(loggerName, logger);
           }
           return logger;
        }

        private static NLog.LogLevel LogLevelToNLogLevel(LogEventLevel level)
        {
            switch (level)
            {
                case LogEventLevel.Verbose:
                    return NLog.LogLevel.Trace;
                case LogEventLevel.Debug:
                    return NLog.LogLevel.Debug;
                case LogEventLevel.Information:
                    return NLog.LogLevel.Info;
                case LogEventLevel.Warning:
                    return NLog.LogLevel.Warn;
                case LogEventLevel.Error:
                    return NLog.LogLevel.Error;
                case LogEventLevel.Fatal:
                    return NLog.LogLevel.Fatal;
                default:
                    return NLog.LogLevel.Trace;
            }
        }
    }
    public static class NLogSinkExtensions
    {
        public static AppBuilder LogToNLog(
            this AppBuilder builder,
            LogEventLevel level = LogEventLevel.Warning,
            params string[] areas)
        {
            Logger.Sink = new NLogSink(level, areas);
            return builder;
        }
    }
}
```

And then setup like this:

```cs
public static AppBuilder BuildAvaloniaApp()
    => AppBuilder.Configure<App>()
        .UsePlatformDetect()
        .LogToNLog();
```

See also: https://gist.github.com/graealex/43f5667c33df8e33bf60981887b49448

See also: https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/getting-started/logging-errors-and-warnings